# Can not find google fusion tables in my documents

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-fusion-tables

I've just started to play around with google fusion tables APIs so maybe I'm missing something...

Starting from a google's simple example

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/fusiontables-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/fusiontables/cmdline/FusionTablesSample.java?repo=samples

and I've just managed to have account server authentication (I've downloaded the key file from Google APIs Console with my account). 
The example works, creates and lists new tables, but I connot find them in my documents.
Where are those tables and how can I access them?

M@rco

Here is my code:

```
private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
        .setServiceAccountId("xxxxxx")
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(FusionTablesSample.class.getResource("/privatekey.p12").toURI()))
        .setServiceAccountScopes(FusiontablesScopes.FUSIONTABLES)
        .build();
    return credential;
}
```

Comment: If you create FTs from within the drive.google.com interface, do you see them in the list via the API?

Comment: Yes, I can see all tables listed via APIs. I was just wondering why they weren't shown in my account documents.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then you created a service account and downloaded the keyfile of that account. Then you used this file and the id of the service account (something like **123456789-fg8dhs8d7sjhsd7asdh76d6dui@developer.gserviceaccount.com**). Right?

If this is the case, it's very simple: *the table belongs the the **service account** not your own account*. You have several possibilities to access the tables via the web UI. The easiest might be to share the table with your own Google account in order to see it in your document list.

Use the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions#resource) to change the permissions of a Fusion Table ([see the example](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert#examples)).

Comment: How to share your table with your own google account to see it in your document list .    And what permissions to be given ...can you be bit more detailed ..

Comment: You create a service account in the [Google API console](https://code.google.com/apis/console). This service account is **not the same as your account**. You simply need to share the Fusion Table with the service account (check it's e-mail address in the API console).

Comment: I got your point ....But can you please let me know how to do it since i am not able to do it